# Tiling image in a Grid

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8.1

How can I tile a single image (small size) multiple times in a `Grid` container so that it appears that the `Grid` is holding one single image instead of multiple images tiled together?

I've seen methods that create a single image by copying the smaller image multiple times by blitting, but that process is computationally expensive. I don't want to create a bigger image; I just want to use the same single image multiple times so that the process doesn't require CPU cycles.

How can this be done?

**UPDATE:** It seems there exists no easy way to do the above. So, as a workaround, how can I create a single larger image by tiling multiple smaller images together in WP8.1 RT?

Comment: Have you tried using a WrapPanel/WrapGrid and just add your image a bunch of times, which will then wrap as long as there's space, and it will seem like they are "one big image"?

Comment: Is it the question, how to programatically generate n * n tile grid with the same img in the cells without the borders, that separate them?

Comment: This should do it, but I want the image to scale to multiple layout sizes depending on device's screen size. This probably means I add the same image enough times so that the image size scales to all possible sizes, but I guess that would produce some ugly XAML code.

Comment: @ntohl yes, that's what I would like to do. I want to avoid any bit level copying operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code I have instantiated only one bitmap image. Tho, I'm not sure, if it is memory conserving.

```
{
      int n = 5;
      Grid grid = new Grid();
      BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/StackOverflowTest;Component/1.jpg"));
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
          grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition {Width = GridLength.Auto});
          grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition {Height= GridLength.Auto});
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
          {                
              Image image = new Image { Source = bitmapImage };
              Grid.SetRow(image, i);
              Grid.SetColumn(image, j);
              grid.Children.Add(image);
          }
      }
      containerOfGrid.Children.Add(grid);
}
```

**EDIT**:

I have checked, and it seems to me, in Immediate window, that the source image is not allocated multiple times.

```
((System.Windows.Controls.Image)((new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView(((System.Windows.Controls.Panel)(grid)).Children)).Items[0]))._bitmapSource.GetHashCode()
37855919
((System.Windows.Controls.Image)((new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView(((System.Windows.Controls.Panel)(grid)).Children)).Items[1]))._bitmapSource.GetHashCode()
37855919
((System.Windows.Controls.Image)((new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView(((System.Windows.Controls.Panel)(grid)).Children)).Items[0])).GetHashCode()
19914648
((System.Windows.Controls.Image)((new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView(((System.Windows.Controls.Panel)(grid)).Children)).Items[1])).GetHashCode()
3378500
```

Comment: It works and is quite fast, but there is a flaw. When I open the page and the above code executes, I can see a flash of the separator lines at the boundaries of the tile image. Though these lines disappear quickly, it's bad UX. I tried using Lumia Imaging SDK, but its output image also has some blurry lines at the boundaries of tile. (See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472176/lumia-imaging-sdk-image-blending-creates-separation-lines).

Comment: These are the separation flashes I was talking about: http://i.imgur.com/wnWSbjB.jpg. They appear for a split second only though.

Comment: Strange. My first advice would be to use double buffering, but wpf already uses DirectX with default double buffering...

Comment: @Flipper Did You manage to solve that in [chat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472176/lumia-imaging-sdk-image-blending-creates-separation-lines#comment51124503_31535510)? Do You have solution?

Comment: The provided solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472176/lumia-imaging-sdk-image-blending-creates-separation-lines should work

Comment: No, I still have the issue. No resolutions. Tried four methods now, none work.