# Lumia Imaging SDK image blending creates separation lines

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, lumia-imaging-sdk

I'm trying to create a tiled background using the Lumia Imaging SDK's `JpegTools.BlendAsync()` method. I call the method in a loop to merge all the tiled images. The approach works but the there are unwanted lines in the output image. These separation lines appear at the boundaries of the single tile image; the merging is not clean.

My code is attached. Am I doing something wrong logically or this is a bug in the SDK?

`bitmapSource` is the single tile, `jpegSource` is the empty layout which is populated by the tile, and `bgSize` is the size of the dimensions of the background.

```
async private static Task<IBuffer> CreateTile(IBuffer jpegSource, IReadableBitmap bitmapSource, Size tileSize, Size bgSize)
        {
            int outBgWidth = (int)bgSize.Width;
            int outBgHeight = (int)bgSize.Height;
            int tileWidth = (int)tileSize.Width;
            int tileHeight = (int)tileSize.Height;

            int currentBgWidth = 0;
            int currentBgHeight = 0;

            Point blendPosition = new Point(0, 0);

            while (currentBgHeight < outBgHeight)
            {
                while (currentBgWidth < outBgWidth)
                {
                    jpegSource = await JpegTools.BlendAsync(jpegSource, bitmapSource, blendPosition);
                    blendPosition.X += tileWidth;
                    currentBgWidth += tileWidth;
                }
                blendPosition.Y += tileHeight;
                currentBgHeight += tileHeight;
                currentBgWidth = 0;
                blendPosition.X = 0;
            }

            return jpegSource;
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide an image of the result, so we can see what kind of artefacts you see? It could be just off-by-one problems in the loop, or indeed a bigger problem - perhaps within the sdk.

Comment: You can also try achieving the same result by using "local blending" feature of the BlendEffect (or BlendingFilter depending on the version of the SDK you are using). Look at the BlendEffect.TargetArea property to achieve this.

Comment: @DavidBožjak I get this: http://i.imgur.com/jmWKWmi.jpg with the above given loop. I'm able to improve the quality by overlapping one pixel to get this: http://i.imgur.com/bXpkIUa.jpg. The second one is bit better, but the lines are still visible.

Comment: Interesting. At this point I can only recommend to do this work with BlendFilter/BlendEffect's local blending instead. JpegTools are a set of legacy API's that aren't being actively looked at: I can't see anything _wrong_ in your code and there aren't aditional options you could try tweaking to achieve a different result.

Comment: The artefact might be the result of a Jpeg quality, which you can not regulate with JpegTools, but you can control with a JpegRenderer. I strongly encorage you to investigate the Source -> BlendEffect -> JpegRenderer pattern instead.

Comment: @DavidBožjak I'm not able to figure out which method should I use to in BlendEffect library. Also, I've used JpegRenderer before for compression and resizing, but I couldn't find any options that enable image merging. Can you please point me in some direction?

Comment: Ok. I will write it as an anwser to the question, even though it's really an alternate way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, I suggest an alternate way of doing this: By using a more "standard" rendering chain, instead of using JpegTools.

Some of this is based on your code sample, but I've tried making it as general as possible.

```
int outBgWidth = (int)bgSize.Width;
int outBgHeight = (int)bgSize.Height;
int tileWidth = (int)tileSize.Width;
int tileHeight = (int)tileSize.Height;

int currentBgWidth = 0;
int currentBgHeight = 0;

Point blendPosition = new Point(0, 0);

using (var backgroundCanvas = new ColorImageSource(new Size(outBgWidth, outBgHeight), Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0)))  //Create a black canvas with the output size.
using (var tileSource = new BitmapImageSource(bitmapSource))
using (var renderer = new JpegRenderer(backgroundCanvas))
{
    while (currentBgHeight < outBgHeight)
    {
        while (currentBgWidth < outBgWidth)
        {
            var blendEffect = new BlendEffect();
            blendEffect.BlendFunction = BlendFunction.Normal;
            blendEffect.GlobalAlpha = 1.0;

            blendEffect.Source = renderer.Source;
            blendEffect.ForegroundSource = tileSource;
            blendEffect.TargetArea = new Rect(blendPosition, new Size(0, 0));   //Since we are PreservingSize the size doesn't matter. Otherwise it must be in relative coordinate space!
            blendEffect.TargetOutputOption = OutputOption.PreserveSize;

            renderer.Source = blendEffect;

            currentBgWidth += tileWidth;
            blendPosition.X = (double)currentBgWidth / (double)outBgWidth;  //Careful, the target area is in relative coordinates
        }

        currentBgHeight += tileHeight;
        blendPosition.Y = (double)currentBgHeight / (double)outBgHeight;    //Careful, the target area is in relative coordinates
        blendPosition.X = 0.0;
        currentBgWidth = 0;
    }

    var result = await renderer.RenderAsync();   //An IBuffer containing the Jpeg file
}
```

I have tried this solution in a sample and I can't see any artifacts. Please do come back and report your results though!

Comment: Based on this anwser I have added a new ImageProvider "RepeatedTileImageSource" to the LumiaImagingSDK-Extras open source project: https://github.com/Microsoft/Lumia-Imaging-SDK-Extras

Comment: The solution works but I still get the unwanted separation lines(here: http://i.imgur.com/Et8LURO.jpg). Can you try with this (http://i.imgur.com/ADNbiGb.jpg) and see what you get?

Comment: @Flipper I'm sorry, but I can't see any seperation lines: http://i.imgur.com/COSWydf.jpg Are you sure you are passing the correct dimensions in for tileSize?

Comment: @Flipper since you are only seeing vertical seperation lines, and not horizotnal ones, it would explain it if you were 1 pixels off there (or something)

Comment: I've tried both on Win8.1x86 and on a lumia 630 WinPhone 8.1. What are you using?

Comment: I tried on Microsoft Lumia 535 and Nokia Lumia 920. I'm not passing the image dimensions manually; I'm calculating them using ImageProperties (StorageFile.Properties). And I can see some horizontal lines too, but they're quite subtle. I think there's some issue with my code here. I'm sharing it here (http://pastebin.com/K0CRP2tq, http://pastebin.com/33zykeyS) but I'll try to find the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Just to make sure you could aso use LumiaImagingSDK to get the dimensions. You can call GetInfoAsync()  on your source. The returned ImageProperties will have a "ImageSize" property. Can't think why they would differ, but perhaps it's worth a shot.

Comment: I checked the image sizes by adding a breakpoint, and they are correct. Must be some other issue. But nice information; I find the SDK documentation a bit lacking.

Comment: Could you suggest some improvements? We can also move this into a chat.

Comment: I'm still unable to resolve the issue. I even used your library at Github, but I still get the unwanted separation lines, on both phones Lumia and 920. Can we discuss over [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84460/lumia-imaging-sdk)?